# Hash Tables with Threads in Perl

Tags: perl

I wrote the following short script, and I keep on getting the error:

```
Invalid value for shared scalar at E:\Scripts\Threads.pl line 19.
```

I don't know why since I am using shared values in a shared array.

```
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $totalInstances = 0;
my $totalDest = 0;
my $totalResults = 0;
my @threads = threads->self();
my @resultsHash : shared = ();
my $dest : shared = ();
my $hostname : shared = ();
my @destinations : shared = ();
my @hostnames : shared = ();
@destinations={"London","NYC"};
@hostnames={"wev1010","web1111"};




foreach $dest (@destinations) {
    foreach $hostname (@hostnames) {
    push @threads, threads->new(\&ParsingResponse,$hostname,$dest);

    }
    sleep(6);
}

foreach (@threads) {
    my $retval = eval ($_->join());
    if ($@) {
    print ERRFILE "Thread failed: $@";
    }
 }

###########################################
# Parsing response 
#  
###########################################
sub ParsingResponse
{
    push @resultsHash, {            
    dest => "$dest",
    hostname => "$hostname",

    }

}
```

Line 19 in my code is:
@destinations={"London","NYC"};

Updated script:

```
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

our @threads = threads->self();
our %resultsHash : shared = ();
our $dest : shared = ();
our $hostname : shared = ();
our @destinations : shared = ();
our @hostnames : shared = ();

@destinations[0]="London";
@destinations[1]="Paris";
@hostnames[0]="wev1010";
@hostnames[1]="web1111";

sub ParsingResponse
{

$resultsHash{$dest}= "$hostname";

}



foreach $dest (@destinations) {

        foreach $hostname (@hostnames) {

    push @threads, threads->new(\&ParsingResponse,$hostname,$dest);

        }     
}



foreach (@threads) {

        my $retval = eval ($_->join());

        if ($@) {

                print "Thread failed: $@";

    }
}
```

Comment: Which one is line 19? In your snippet, line 19 is a blank line.

Comment: @destinations={"London","NYC"};

Comment: You are trying to use multithreading for some problem, but it's likely the wrong solution. You don't seem to know much Perl, e.g. arrays are initialized like `@array = ("foo", "bar")` – no curlies! That `eval($_->join())` won't quite do what you want! Avoid shared data if possible, and re-read [the thread::shared docs](http://p3rl.org/threads::shared). For communication between threads, you should rather use a [`Thread::Queue`](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Queue).

Comment: I changed it to be at (). I have to used shared (the script here is much more shorter than it really is). Now I have the folowing error:

Comment: Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at E:\Scripts\pr
iceCompare\ShortSearchHotelsWithThreads.pl line 54.
Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at E:\Scripts\pr
iceCompare\ShortSearchHotelsWithThreads.pl line 54.

Comment: Re update, Don't join the main thread (which you got using `threads->self()` at the top), and you want `eval { ... }` instead of `eval ( ... )`. The latter evaluates the result of `join`, while the former catches exceptions thrown by `join`. I don't think `join` can throw an exception, though.

Answer (score 3):

`@destinations` is shared, but the hash created by `{ }` isn't. Use

```
@destinations = share({"London","NYC"});
```

But as sundar points out, you probably don't want a hash in the first place.

```
@destinations = ("London", "NYC");
```

Comment: The OP's intention is most probably to assign elements to the array there, rather than to create an anon hash and assign a single reference to that.

Comment: I do to use a hash, I just gave here a very short version of the script I have. When I used @destinations = share({"London","NYC"}); I got the folowing error:

Comment: There's very probably something wrong between that `@destinations` assignment and the `foreach` loop, I'd recommend you to go through http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html before attempting work on deeper topics like threads.

Comment: I changed the script to:

Comment: ###########################################
# Parsing response 
#  
###########################################

sub ParsingResponse
{


$resultsHash{"$dest"}= "$hostname";



 
}

The error I have now is:
Cannot join a detached thread at E:\Scripts\priceCompare\ShortSearchHotelsWithTh
reads.pl line 36.

Comment: The script you posted does not exhibit that problem.